# Extracting dates with a common point in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Imagine a pile of data recording when it rained and in which state,

```
State/Date 01Jan 02Jan 03Jan 04Jan 05Jan 
Alabama     YES   YES   NO    YES   NO
Alaska      YES   YES   YES   NO    YES
Florida     NO    NO    NO    YES   NO
Nevada      NO    YES   NO    YES   NO
```

How do I write a formula giving me a list of dates that rained in a particular state?
Eg, I want to know when it rained in Nevada. Could I get the answer `02Jan, 04Jan` in a cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Below show method solves the issue:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- For faster results, create Drop Down for States in Cell A28.
- Hit Data TAB then Data Validation.
- For List Source, select D28:D31.

[image]

- Now for Rain or No Rain create Drop down in cell B28, using Data Validation and for List Source add Yes & No.

[image]

- Now the final an Array (CSE) formula in cell A35:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($E$27:$I$27,1,SMALL(IF(INDEX($E$28:$I$31,MATCH($A$28,$D$28:$D$31,0),)=$B$28,COLUMN($A$26:$E$26)),ROW(1:1))),"")}
  ```

**N.B.**

- Finish the formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for the formula, it certainly solved my problem of extracting the dates from the data. Now, I could TEXTJOIN everything which works but I need to squeeze all that into a cell which is of a fixed dimension due to formatting. Currently, combinations of large amount of dates exceed the size of the cell, so I switched the dates to only using "DD" format. Which gives me, for example, `02,03,04,06,07,10,11,15,16,17`. And I know this is probably extremely unefficient but is it possible to make said cell somehow display `02-04, 06-07, 10-11, 15-17` or something of the sort?

Comment: Glad to help you @Que ,, since no where you have disclosed that the way u r using  TEXTJOIN so difficult for me to be judgmental about it, but yes by using my formula DATEs can be altered in MM-DD or MM/DD or in other,, simply you need to use the TEXT function after IFFERROR and before the IFERROR value insert the "MM-DD" format or you can directly apply the required format on cells too ☺

Comment: Glad to help U @Que,,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 1):

Truthfully, just making a pivot table from your data would probably be your best approach. But if you want a formula approach:

Say your data is in cells A1:F5, including headers. Then, if your lookup value is in cell G8, the following:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,TEXT(IFERROR(IF(IF(XLOOKUP(G8,A2:A5,B2:F5)="YES",B1:F1,"0")/IF(XLOOKUP(G8,A2:A5,B2:F5)="YES",B1:F1,"0")>0,IF(XLOOKUP(G8,A2:A5,B2:F5)="YES",B1:F1,"0"),""),""),"dd-mmm"))
```

gives you an output that looks like:

**02-Jan, 04-Jan**

if "Nevada" is looked for.

And so on.

Basically, it uses the first `XLOOKUP()` to find the row of YES and NO data that applies to the state. The `IF()` wrapping that gives 0 for NO's and the date in the header row for YES's. That is wrapped by an `IF()` that uses the preceding result divided by itself (which produces ERROR's and 1's) in a check to see if the result is >0 which the 1's are. Those ERROR's will continue forward, but the second `IF()` replaces the 1's with the dates again. Then an `IFERROR()` wraps that to reduce the result to only those items which were dates, not ERROR's. They are Excel integer date values (43563, say) at this point and it would seem they are desired in the form they appear in the header row, so `TEXT()` formats them so. The fact that they lose their "number-ness" in doing so is not a problem as they would do so in any case if listed out (well, unless only one date were returned... if one wants to "be technical"...). Finally, `TEXTJOIN()` gives then a "comma-space" separator for readability (and so they have a separator that can be used to extract one or all, if needed in further work).

Likely there are other approaches, the `XLOOKUP()` version of the longstanding "double INDEX/MATCH" technique might be one, though getting multiple resposes from `XLOOKUP()` was giving me multiple responses (5, as expected), but they were three 01-Jan's and two 02-Jan's, not, for instance, the 02-Jan and 04-Jan I wanted. It's 3 am here though, so maybe I missed something there. `FILTER()` was acting too quickly, losing me the positional info to get the two dates for Nevada (immediately just the two results, but now 1-2, not 2-4, so no good way to get the dates out of the header). Might be other ideas. Again though, 3 am...

Probably doesn't matter though as each would be a pile of elements, like the above, so reducing it to something simple looking probably can't happen.

Comment: You mentioned pivot tables but I'm unable to get a table that actually makes sense. I suspect my variables arent in the correct categories? Best I could get is to put the country variable in the report filter.